# DebugActiveProcess is returning false result

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to suspend a process using DebugActiveProcess but result is not returng true and Failed to attach to process. How can I make it workable?

```
string processName = "notepad"; 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
            if (processes.Length > 0)
            {
                int processId = processes[0].Id;
                Console.WriteLine("Process ID: " + processId);

                // Get the process ID of the process you want to suspend
 
                // Attach to the process and suspend it
                bool result = DebugActiveProcess(processId);
                if (result == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to attach to process");
                    return;
                }
                // The process is now suspended. Do your debugging tasks here.
                // Detach from the process
                Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
                process.WaitForInputIdle(); // Wait for the process to become idle
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 5 * 60);

                DebugActiveProcessStop(processId);
            }
```

I am trying to suspend a process using DebugActiveProcess

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, But when I create a **new console application** and make sure it doesn't have other codes, It worked for me. The DebugActiveProcess returning true(successful).

So I'm going to suspend a process through another console application,
And I guess there are some codes that aren't yours, and they did change the environments of your application.